# css: how to create gap between vertical divs, using only one css instruction

Tags: html, css, position, space

How to create a vertical gap between the only neighboring blocks, but not between the parent elements, using only one css instruction.

```
<div>BLOCK1</div>
<div>
<!-- vertical gap disabled -->
<div>BLOCK2.1</div>
<!-- vertical gap enabled -->
<div>BLOCK2.2</div>
<!-- vertical gap enabled -->
<div>BLOCK2.3</div>
<!-- vertical gap disabled -->
</div>
<div>BLOCK3</div>
```

margin-bottom (or margin-top) - incorrect result (vertical gap between BLOCK2.3 and BLOCK3 for margin-bottom or between BLOCK1 and BLOCK2.1 for margin-top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use the direct child selector `>`  see: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators

from your bit of code it might be used this way:

```css
body>div {margin:1em 0;}
```

```html
<div>BLOCK1</div>
<div>
  <!-- vertical gap disabled -->
  <div>BLOCK2.1</div>
  <!-- vertical gap enabled -->
  <div>BLOCK2.2</div>
  <!-- vertical gap enabled -->
  <div>BLOCK2.3</div>
  <!-- vertical gap disabled -->
</div>
<div>BLOCK3</div>
```

Comment: Very clever, thank you for sharing - If it weren't for you I would have gone the long way and added an id to the Block 1 and 3 div then added margin with CSS.

Comment: no. no
need other result

HEADER --- NO GAP --- BLOCK2.1 --- GAP --- BLOCK2.3 --- GAP --- BLOCK2.5 --- NO GAP --- FOOTER

https://jsfiddle.net/Zhihar/gw8g85x5/3/ (for example, brutforce css)

Comment: @Zhihar Then just update the selector https://jsfiddle.net/gw8g85x5/4/ did you not understood how it worked ? https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators

Comment: @GCyrillus, your last link is not the result that I need
It is necessary for me that the top and lower gaps were absent

Comment: @Zhihar oups, didnot follow your link actually, then select each div after the second https://jsfiddle.net/gw8g85x5/5/  You should dig a bit into selectors and play with them, lots of things can be done without ids nor class :)

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, I understood your idea, it really elementary and coolly. But 2 columns are a special case, unfortunately :(
(https://jsfiddle.net/Zhihar/gw8g85x5/6/). I thought just about something more universal, when the quantity of columns isn't known.